# PHP serialize Object Injection in utf8 MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, object, serialization, code-injection

before anything I'd like to state that I would **NEVER** do anything like this. I'm doing a small audit on a project and I found they are serializing the entire $_POST array and saving them as article comments, I have replicated the scenario in the code below:

```
    <?php
        /*
                CREATE TABLE `comments` (
                        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `data` mediumtext NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
        */

        ini_set('display_errors','On');
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $comments = Array();

        try{

                $options = [
                                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'

                ];

                $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
                $pdo = new \PDO($dsn,'user','password',$options);
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                if($_POST){

                        $comment = serialize($_POST);
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments SET data = :data";
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bindValue(':data',serialize($_POST));
                        $stmt->execute();

                }

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT data FROM comments');
                $stmt->execute();
                $comments = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }catch(\Exception $e){

                echo $e->getMessage();

        }
?>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>My nice little comment form</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <form method="POST" action="" enctype="text/plain">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                        <br />
                        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                        <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                </form>
                <?php foreach($comments as $comment):?>
                        <?php $data = unserialize($comment['data']);?>
                        <p>Name: <?php echo $data['name']; ?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $data['comment'];?></p>
                <?php endforeach;?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Due to the table encoding (which is incorrect) if you would insert a unicode character in the name such as  the output would be truncated resulting in a possible object injection

**Examples:**

**Data set 1: No injection**

- name = John
- comment = My Comment
- Table data value = a:2:{s:4:"name";s:4:"John";s:7:"comment";s:10:"My comment";}

**Data set 2: Object injection**

- name  = John";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:4:"test";i:1;};s:4:blah;s:1:"comment"}
- comment = Whatever
- Table data value = a:2:{s:4:"name";s:**69**:"John";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:4:"test";i:1;};s:4:blah;s:1:"comment"}

In the last case, we can see that the injection is in fact somewhat successful, however, the string length of the value pertaining to the name (John) is incorrect, it should be 4 instead of **69** for the injection to be successful in order to be executed when unserialize is invoked.

I've tried several approaches, such as, inserting null characters, backspace characters, delete characters and what not but I can't get it to work.

The devs are saying "it's not vulnerable" so I was hoping someone could help me find proof that it is actually vulnerable.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `name` is `John";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:4:"test";i:1;};s:4:blah;s:1:"comment"}` which is 69 bytes long.

Comment: Yes, the question refers to how actually we could make serialize think John is 4 and not 69 if such thing is even possible in order to unserialize to be executed successfully. There is no confusion on the unicode character being 4 bytes long, thanks.

Comment: `serialize` is probably a bad idea if you're worried about injection. Instead use `json_encode` to dump out what should be a dumb, platform-independent data structure. MySQL 5.7 even supports `JSON` as a native column type. It will never support PHP's native `serialize` format.

Comment: As I stated at the top: "before anything I'd like to state that I would NEVER do anything like this. I'm doing a small audit on a project and I found they are serializing the entire $_POST array and saving them as article comments"